# Gradient with fading in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, linear-gradients

My question is about gradient with fading: gradient - from top to bottom, and fading - from left to right.

Example:

[image]

The code is:

```
background-image: 
  linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(198,83,165,.95) 0%, rgba(198,86,51,.95) 100%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%);
opacity: 0.949;
```

My result is below.

[image]

As you see, it doesn't fade the gradient, it looks like separate layer, behind this gradient. Is there any other method of implementing this?

Comment: Transparent will only show the layer that is behind (which is the one with the color) and so this approach won't work. You'll have to use some other way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I had mentioned in comments, when you add a transparent layer on top of another gradient, it will only show through the colored gradient layer that is below it (and not the image that is present in the container). So, it would be very tough (almost impossible) to achieve this with gradients.

You'd have to use a mask image to achieve it. The below is a snippet that uses a **SVG mask**.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
div svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div .grad-fill {
  fill: url(#grad);
  mask: url(#masker);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="rotate(270,0.5,0.5)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(198,83,165,.95)" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(198,86,51,.95)" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="mask-grad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="black" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id="masker" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="url(#mask-grad)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" class="grad-fill" />
  </svg>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/animals/8" />
</div>
```

You can find more information about **SVG masks** in the below links:

- [SVG Clipping and Masking - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking)
- [SVG Masks Tutorials @ JENKOV.COM](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/mask.html)

---

This can be done with pure CSS also but unfortunately [`mask-image` property is currently supported only by WebKit browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) and so this approach is not recommended.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}
div:after,
img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(198, 83, 165, .95) 0%, rgba(198, 86, 51, .95) 100%);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 40%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Some text
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/animals/8" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can see the gradient in your last snippet, but can't see `Abcd`. Where'd it go?

Comment: I enjoy when you say something would be almost impossible !

Comment: Nice attempt @vals but I don't think it produces the same effect. But yeah, with CSS and gradients, that is the closest that can be achieved.

Comment: How to make the fade vertically?

Answer (score 5):

A way to create this effect with pure CSS is to play with multiple radial gradients, and with the transparency of each

behind the radial gradients, that are quite transparent to allow them to fade in between them, there is a linear gradient that provides opacity (in white) to the right side.

If you want this to be more accurate, you can set more radial gradients, each covering a part of the image.

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  background: 
  radial-gradient(ellipse 70% 100% at top right, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), transparent),   
               radial-gradient(ellipse 70% 100% at bottom right, rgba(255,0,80,0.5), transparent),
               linear-gradient(to left, white 20%, transparent);
  background-size: 100% 80%, 100% 80%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: top left, left 100%, top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/400/nature);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use vertical gradient for your colored background, but use png-mask for fading.

Look at these examples of using PNG masks: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

The rest is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using a png for your gradient in a background with `background-size: contain`.

Advantage:

- works on all browsers (not <= IE8)

Inconveniences:

- need image editor to change colors
- the PNG could be heavy (depend of its size)
- you don’t control very well the way the gradient is applied

```css
.test > div {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.test p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/150/nature) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I’m using a base64 image instead of  PNG file image to not have to look for a server, but of course, it works fine with a file image)